# How do I compare input value and assign, in one line in Python?

Tags: python

It's a simple task but I would still like to compress it down to learn new methods.

Suppose I want a value (eg. a number) from a user, but they enter an invalid input (" "), then I can assign a default (=5) value like so:

```
-> number = int(input("Enter Number: ") or 5)
```

In this method if the user inputs -1 , the code still works, number = -1.
But, what if want to check if the value is greater than 2:

```
-> number = int( int("Enter Number: ") >2 or 5)

-> Enter Number: 10

-> print(number)

-> 1
```

**the logical value of 10>2 = 1 is assigned and printed**

Is there a way to compare the value and assign accoudingly, *In One Statement*

Comment: Not without creating one or more helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this on one line, so you would need to write the extra lines or (possibly a better option) write a helper function for it. You should likely also check for other invalid inputs. Example:

```
def get_value_or_default(minimum: int = 2, default: int = 5) -> int:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter Number: "))
    except ValueError:
        return default
    
    return number if number >= minimum else default
```

With output:

```
>>> get_value_or_default()
Enter Number: 1
5
>>> get_value_or_default()
Enter Number: 2
2
>>> get_value_or_default()
Enter Number: 3
3
>>> get_value_or_default()
Enter Number: oops
5
```

Comment: I get that, and using functions is the way to approach the result, but I wanted like a one line flexible solution,
I know this one below is incorrect syntax, but like it could generate some idea:
[Check if number greater than 0, if negative assign value 5 to variable a]

>> a = 5 if i<0 else i for i in int(input(": "))

I really would like to find an answer.

Comment: @MaT4X Keep in mind readability is important. Just because it's "pythonic" and done in one line doesn't mean it's the best way to do it.

Comment: @MaT4X It's not that I'm withholding the information, I simply don't believe this is possible in one line. I tried some absolutely horrible formulations out of curiosity and came up with nothing.

Comment: I agree that its not, like a practical thing to do in a code. I just asked the question to know if this was possible, that was all. Thank you for attempting to look for the method. I still would be continuing to try to find some wacky code to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial solution (it can only handle integers, not the example space character) not testing for exceptions from Python 3.8 and above:

```
number = num if ((num:=int(input("Enter Number: "))) >2 ) else 5
```

This is a ternary operator with an [assigment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) inside.
Be careful, there is one more pair of parentheses needed then I expected at first, encapsulating the assignment expression before the comparison, otherwise the result will be just "True", since the variable will take up the expression value.
This is the reason why I looked into this (taking this to the next level):

```
getlatestorclosestdl(s if (re.search("^[0-9]{14}$",s:=input("Timestamp to approximate (yyyymmddHHMMSS): "))) else None)
```

This looks for the specific form of timestamp as input, or will call the method without arguments, which will default the timestamp to the current second. I really wanted to do this as a one-liner.